# How to solve error "Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource not found" az sql db import throws

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops, devops, bacpac

As part of my Azure Devops release pipeline I want to restore the bacpac of the previous days data from Azure storage.

I am running the following az command

```
az sql db import -s myprod.database.windows.net -n mydb
-g myresourcegroup -p "${mypassword}" -u myuser
--storage-key "${mystoragekey}" --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey 
--storage-uri 
"https://mystore.blob.core.windows.net/db/bk$(date -d "yesterday" '+%Y-%m-%d').bacpac"
```

This command fails with the following `ERROR: Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'myprod.database.windows.net/mydb' not found.`

The db already exists on the server. Is this saying that the parent in this case is the server or the db? It should be able to find both

Comment: This article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-parent-resource-errors) describes the errors you may get when deploying a resource that is dependent on a parent resource.

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT the article doesn't explain this in the scenario when using the azure cli. It just describes that you should use the same resource-group when the server is already there. I do that, and it still fails with this message

Comment: Did this get fixed as I have the same issue right now